# How to read cookies from the request in azure function app using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-triggers

I created a azure HTTP triggered function app using python which accepts request and return response based on the request parameters. Now I want read the cookies from the request. How to read the cookie from request?

Comment: Is this using Azure Functions V1 or V2? The python support is very different (and improved) in V2.

Comment: Yes. I'm using version 2. @ConnorMcMahon.

Answer (score 1):

You would just have to load/parse the `Cookie` header from the `req` object using [`http.cookies.SimpleCookie`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html)

```py
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

import azure.functions as func
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    cookie = SimpleCookie()
    cookie.load(req.headers['Cookie'])

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{cookie['username'].value}")
```

To test this code, send a request with header like this

```
Cookie: username=oreo
```

Comment: Is there a list of all available req headers? I need hostname but I can't find the python syntax/list of available headers.

Comment: HTTP Headers are populated into a dictionary. Any [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) passed in the request should be available. Hostname would be in the [Host Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host).